# Javascript array in external file?

Tags: javascript, arraylist, discord.js

I have a large profanity list, as an array. Since this list is so big, I don't want it in my main file, but externally. I want something like this:

`const blacklist = require(./blacklist.js)`

And currently it is something like this:

```
const blacklist = [
"1",
"2",
"3"
]
```

The rest of the code here is:

```
 blacklist.forEach((word) => {
      if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word));
      message.delete();
      message.channel.send("Let's try to keep it family friendly!");
```

And will that last piece of code still work?

Comment: You need to export your constant somehow. How you do it depends on what module system you use. If you use standard JS, you just need to write `export const ...` and then in your other file you can write `import {blacklist} from './filepath'`.

Comment: You can read more about the module system here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Discord.js` is based on `NodeJS`, so:

**blacklist.js** :

```
module.exports =
[
    "1",
    "2",
    "3"
]
```

**app.js** :

```
const blacklist = require('./blacklist.js');
blacklist.forEach(word => { console.log(word) });
```